# android - Handling app start up in non main activity

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I just noticed android pretends to resume your app after killing it in the background by restarting you at the activity you were previously on.

1) Can I disable this feature?

My problems lies in my ListsActivity. It is passed a lists array which contains items to display to the user. Some are folders - when selected I open another ListsActivity with an array containing the contents of that folder. The lists can be generated dynamically for example if the user decides to search on all the items in a specific folder and its subfolders.

If my app restarts in my ListsActivity I have no idea where I am without that lists array.

2) What should I do?

-- I don't want to persist the array every time onPause is called. The array could be huge at the top of the tree. Not to mention all the ListsActivities in the back history.

3) Is it possible to seamlessly restart the app from the ListsActivity onCreate if I find I don't have my lists array? I mean without showing The ListsActivity then blinking away to the main activity.

EDIT - Note that this involves recursion since the user could have any number of activities in the history at any point in time. So I have another question:

4) If restarted in this fashion - when I hit back do I have the full back history? Every one of those activities also has to be created again right?  I opened another question to ask how to test this here: [How to test your app being killed and restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488228/how-to-test-your-app-being-killed-and-restarted)

Comment: What do you mean "android pretends to resume your app after killing..."? Are you talking about pressing the "Home" `button`? Is the only problem that you don't know what directory you are in? I guess I'm a bit confused on what the actual issue is?

Comment: When your app is in the background android can kill it and then "resume" it by recreating the app but starting the user in the activity he left off at.

Comment: So for example I have a 2 megabyte tree in memory containing folders. I have one activity which displays each folder and I pass a pointer to that folder to this activity. In order to support resume after the app is killed this folder would have to save the entire tree below it to disk.

Comment: I presume that when the system kills and then recreates your activity, the pointer will be null, am I right?

Comment: Yes. The pointer is null. Not only that my app initialization occurs during a loading splash screen which now isn't displayed since we are popping into the middle of the app.  I really need the app to always restart if it has been killed.

Comment: Setting the first activity with android:clearTaskOnLaunch may help. I do not know what happen if say a phone call come in while your list activity is in the foreground and the user answer for a long time and your activity was killed. I have some other idea but why don't you try the above first.

Answer (score 0):

You could call finish() in onPause, when start your app again is reset. Or you can override the method onSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState and onPause are called all the time in normal activity so I really just don't want to be writing files for no reason.